# Column title SQL Script

Tags: sql, c, oracle, shell

How can i add column name on top of the column in sql generated xls ouput file.. I am getting all the data but without column heading .. I am doing this in c shell sql script.. I have my SET HEADINGS ON but still i am not getting my heading.. do i have to do anything else in the sql script to populate the heading...plz help

```
`SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET LONG 100000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET HEADING ON
SET SPACE 1
SET FLUSH OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET NUMFORMAT 9999999999.90

SELECT USER_ID 
From ...
Where...;`
```

Comment: can you please share your query?

Answer (score 2):

please share us your query. What client tool do you use?
Asuming you use sql*plus

```
set heading on
set pages 10000


select dummy user_id
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the `SET PAGESIZE 0` that is causing the normal heading to be suppressed.

> SET PAGESIZE
>
> Sets the number of rows on each page
>   of output in iSQL*Plus, and the number
>   of lines on each page of output in
>   command-line and Windows GUI.
>
> Increase PAGESIZE to avoid printing
>   headings frequently, or **set it to 0 to
>   prevent headings being displayed.**

So one option is to set pagesize to a very large value (50,000 is the largest allowable value in my version of SQLPlus).

If your query is going to produce more rows than that, you will have heading appearing in the middle of the data.  So another option is to keep headings off and add a separate statement to your script to output a header row.  You could use  `SELECT 'USER_ID` FROM DUAL`or`PROMPT USER_ID` to output the text "USER_ID".

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COLUMN_NAME might be what you're looking for...

Comment: i have my data but i want to add column title to say list of data in this column is User_id on top of that data.. how can i add "USER_ID" as column name on top of that data